# Autofilter data in two columns

Tags: excel, vba, filter, autofilter

I have data in two columns. One column is states and the other is for dates.

I want to filter on one state and three months.

When I apply this code all of the data dissapears. It seems as though everything in both of these filters deselect.

months is an ArrayList.

```
Sheets("The Data (2)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$T").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=stateName, Operator:=xlFilterValues
Set months = getMonths(Year, Quarter)
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$T").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=Array(months.Item(0), months.Item(1), months.Item(2)), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Range("$A$1:$T$1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("State Rate Planning Template.xlsm").Activate
Sheets(3).Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your needs. There was a little guess work within the question so if not, feel free to clarify below.

```
Sub untested()
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbook(ThisWorkbook.Name)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("The data (2)")
Dim months As Integer

Set months = getMonths(Year, Quarter)

With ws
  .Range("$A:$T").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=stateName, Operator:=xlFilterValues
  .Range("$A:$T").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=Array(months.Item(0), months.Item(1), months.Item(2)), Operator:=xlFilterValues
  .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("State Rate Planning Template.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Range("A1")
End With

Workbooks("State Rate Planning Template.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this helped!!! There was a minor issue elsewhere that also contributed but you helped me realize a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: if this solved your problem, please consider marking the answer accepted (the check mark under the up/down vote arrows). See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)